# Programatically accessing the definition of typespec

Tags: reflection, types, elixir

How might I access the definition of a typespec within my code? I wish to use it within a macro in order to perform some code generation.

Something like this would be ideal.

Given this module and typespec:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  @type t :: :ok | :error
end
```

I could call a function such as `Code.get_type(MyMod, :t)` and it would return the AST of the definition expression:

```
{:::, [], [{:my_type, [], Elixir}, {:|, [], [:ok, :error]}]}
```

Or alternatively just the AST of the type:

```
{:|, [], [:ok, :error]}
```

Comment: Do you want to access this _after_ the module has been compiled or from within that module?

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack (and works only on compilation stage,) but it does what you want:

```
defmodule MyMod do                                      
  @type t1 :: :ok | :error
  @type t2 :: :done
  @type_defs Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :type, [])
  def type_defs,
    do: Enum.map(@type_defs, fn {:type, type, _} -> type end)
end

MyMod.type_defs
#⇒ [{:::, [line: 9], [{:t2, [line: 9], nil}, :done]},
#   {:::, [line: 8], [{:t1, [line: 8], nil}, {:|, [line: 8], [:ok, :error]}]}]
```

One might declare a module with `defmacro __using__`, implementing this functionality and `use TypeExtractor` whenever needed.